# Where am I going on wrong on this integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question 11 from section 15.4 of Ragowski (2nd edition) reads: solve the following integral by converting to polar coordinates and computing.  The integral is  $$\int_0^5\int_0^yxdxdy$$

The region in question is a right triangular region with a base on the x-axis and vertical side at x=5.  When I convert to polar coordinates, I get $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{5\sec{\theta}}r^2\cos{\theta}drd\theta$$

My issue is that the first integral is $\frac{125}{6}$, and the second is $\frac{125}{3}$.  I have made some error in my conversion of the region to polar coordinates, but I have not been able to locate it.

Unfortunately, I am only one of three people who have come up with this identical conversion, so all three of us are missing something obnoxious, for sure. Any ideas about what it might be?

Update: My error was that I was using the lower triangular region, not the upper one.  As a side note, the solution in Rogawski (2nd edition) shows the lower region as the correct one, and then gives the correct numerical value.  In the 3rd edition, the incorrect region is still shown, but now they give the correct corresponding computation.  So, they fixed one error by replacing it with another one.

Comment: Check your region: your proposed integral would correspond to inner limits of $\int_y^5$ in the original integral.

Comment: It is a bad idea to convert to polar coordinates. The domain is a triangle, not a sector.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The students are being asked in the homework to do it.  I don't think they did it voluntarily. :-)

Comment: This integral takes about 10 seconds if it is computed directly.  The author just wants the student (and apparently instructor) to suffer a little.

Comment: @Trevor: And the editor, too (see the Update).

Answer (score 2):

Your region is a right-triangular region with a base on the $y$-axis and a horizontal side at $y = 5$, isn't it?

If you convert to polar coordinates, you get

$$
\int_{\theta = \pi/4}^{\pi/2}
    \int_{r = 0}^{5 \csc \theta}
         r^2 \cos \theta \, dr \, d\theta
$$

See if that doesn't help.

Comment: This is precisely the error we all made over and over.  The triangle is the upper one, not the lower one.

Comment: And of course that changes the answer because the integrand increases to the right, where the lower triangle has more area.